# ILMerge.Merge : The assembly Serilog was not merged in correctly. It is still listed as an external reference in the target assembly

Tags: .net, serilog, ilmerge

We are trying to change log4net to SeriLog in our enterprise library. the code works fine, but when it tries all the project to merge and make an assembly.... I see this issue
ILMerge.Merge : The assembly Serilog was not merged in correctly. It is still listed as an external reference in the target assembly
I have tried changing the assembly name....it didn't work
Thanks in advance

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code

Comment: The same code is working when i add SeriLog.Sinks.RollingFile but it doesn't work with Serilog.Sinks.File, can't show code here(org constraints)